# Getting wrong time while converting from NSString to NSDate When Device Time format is 24hr

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In Following Code I am trying to convert `NSString` to `NSDate` and once again converting to another Date format and sending it to server.

**Following code worked perfectly fine when my Device Time Format is 12 hr. with dateformat to `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a"];` it gives me correct Date and Time.**

**But As soon as I changed device time Format to 24 hr. and change the datefomatter to `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm a"];`  it gives wrong Date and Time (Specifically time.) I had shown log values for code.**

I had checked lot of stackoverflow questions regarding `NSDateFormatter` and Conversion of `NSString` to `NSDate`. But I am not able to find out where I'm making mistake and why it gives me wrong time when my Device time format is 24hr. Please help me to resolve this.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm a"];
NSString *fromTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"04-Jul-2017 01:46 PM"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:fromTime];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *setdtFrom=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
NSLog(@"From DateTime %@",setdtFrom);
```

*Following log showing Date and Time When My Device Time format is 12hr. And it is Correct one.*
**From DateTime 2017-07-04T13:46:00**

*Time When My Device Time format is 24hr. And it is wrong (specifically time).*
**From DateTime 2017-07-04T12:46:00**

Comment: converting 24 hr format no need of 'a' in your format string

Comment: Your code mistake. HH is  24 hr format. But you add a at the back. You should use hh instead.

Comment: @DSDharma If I remove 'a' it gives null date. Try that code with Time format 24 hr. in your device.

Comment: @GeneCode I had use hh for 12 hr format and it give me correct date and time. Just Try this code with Time format 24 hr. in your device it gives null.

Comment: answer updated , please check it

Comment: @LalKrishna sure I will try your solution

Comment: is it worked? please accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try setting locale & timezone

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale: [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
    NSString *fromTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"04-Jul-2017 01:46 PM"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:fromTime];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *setdtFrom=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
    NSLog(@"From DateTime %@",setdtFrom);
```

Comment: Setting locale is the important. Thanks for the Help, correct answer +1 for solution.